# Using the UIImagePickerController image editor separately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

When you are using an UIImagePickerController, you have a property called **allowsImageEditing**, which makes it possible to zoom in/crop/etc a picture, after you picked a picture (from camera or library).

I would like to use this editor just with an UIImage as a source, the images are loaded from the internet and I want the user to be able to select either a part of an image or zoom in/out on the image, before it is saved to the device.

Is this possible? I cant find an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. UIImagePickerController is just for the camera and/or library.

You may find the TTPhotoViewController (and TTThumbsViewController) from the [Three20](http://three20.info/) project useful.
Apparently that project now even has its own stack exchange: [Three20 Scope](http://three20.stackexchange.com/).